# How can I view the entire layer in Photoshop, even if part of the layer has been dragged outside the edge of the canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a large selection in a separate layer, which, when dragged to where I want it to sit, partly moves outside the canvas. I would like to be able to see the part outside the canvas instead of it being cropped in the view. I'm sure I've seen it done somehow, but I couldn't find it.

I'm using CS4 on Win7, if that matters

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can view the complete layer by selecting `Image > Reveal All`

In my SS you can see, first i let you know the layer is going out from the canvas thats why i used ctrl+t just to show you my layer position. and then reveal all it will reveal the complete layer in front of you.

[image]

hope this is clear and help full

Comment: The shortcut for this on PC is CTRL-0 (control zero).

Comment: my ctrl+0 does zoom at certain level :O

Comment: It works, but looks like Photoshop just re sizes the canvas based on the layers.  Not really the most clever way to do it, infact the performance is awful.

Comment: Ya, this changes your canvas size, rather than let's you simply view items outside the canvas, like you can in illustrator.